# Scope of enumerators

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-errors, scope

In the following, I don't know if i'm confusing enums in C# with C++ but 
  I thought you could only access enumerators in enum using `Forms::shape` which actually gives an error.

```
int main()
{
    enum Forms {shape, sphere, cylinder, polygon};

    Forms form1 = Forms::shape; // error
    Forms form2 = shape; //  ok
}
```

Why is `shape` allowed to be accessed outside of enum without a scope operator and how can i prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, because enums do not form a declarative scope. It is just the way it is in C++. You want  to envelope these enum constants in a dedicated scope, make one yourself: use a wrapper class or namespace.

The upcoming C++ standard will introduce new kind of enum that does produce its own scope.

Comment: Note that the same scoping will be back ported into regular enums in C++0x as well. The difference is that `enum class` will force the scoping, while regular `enum` allows you to use _either_ scoping.

Comment: @NicolBolas `enum class` does not only force scoping, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24488900/2932052)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the enum isn't declared inside a class so it has no particular scope. You could define a struct - a struct is a class where all members are public in C++ - that contains your enum, and use the name of that class to provide the scope.

You could also create a namespace and place your enum inside it as well. But that might be overkill.

Comment: +1, you can also declare enums inside classes, and yes, it's laborious. C++11 introduced [scoped enums](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24488900/2932052) which are easy to use (and more type-safe).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that the underlying reason derives from C compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 introduces [scoped enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations.28since_C.2B.2B11.29), which keep the namespace clean and also prevent unintentional combinations with `int` types. Scoped enums are declared with the keyword sequence `enum class`.

By using *scoped enumerations*, your above example then turns into this:

```
int main()
{
    enum class Forms {shape, sphere, cylinder, polygon}; // mind the "class" here

    Forms form1 = Forms::shape; // ok
    Forms form2 = shape;  // error
}
```